# Вампир, упырь, вурдалак

Tags: этимология

Все знают произведения А.К. Толстого "Упырь" и "Семья вурдалака". Речь фактически об одних и тех же существах. Но интересно, почему разные названия? Как я понимаю, "упырь" - это русское слово, насчет "вурдалака" сомневаюсь. Хотя, вспомним панночку, которая призывала: "Ко мне упыри! Ко мне вурдалаки!" Таким образом, наличествуют оба слова для обозначения некой нечисти.
Было бы интересно узнать происхождение этих слов.

Answer (score 1):

Слово <<**УПЫРЬ**>> конкретно истолковывается через иврит . См . ИРИС-словарь д-ра Баруха Подольского - [ИРИС-словарь](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php) . На иврите **עפר** , по-буквенно (читать справа-налево) : **ע** *аин* , - не имеет конкретного звука , но указывает на гласный , - **פ** *пей* , - звук **П** или **Ф** , - **ר** *реш* - звук **Р** **//** в современном иврите озвучивается , как *афар* , но может озвучиваться и , как **УПР**(=*УПЫРЬ*) в по-буквенном прочтении **//** перевод - **ПРАХ** . Смысловой перевод соответствует понятию <<*мертвец*>> . Обратите внимание , что ивритная **ע** *аин* по написанию очень схожа с кириллической **У** . /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Говоря о слове <<**УПЫРЬ**>> , нелишне упомянуть дошедшее до нас из письменных источников древней Руси имя одного весьма добродетельного новгородского священника XI века . Он звался Упырь Лихой . Тут не следует понимать это имя в прямом смысле . Есть еврейское имя <<Офр(ах) / =Опр(ах)>> **עפרה** , в переводе - *руда* (Офра Хаза ,- **עפרה חזה** , - популярная израильская певица конца XX в.) , пишется так же , как и **עפר** с той лишь разницей , что в конце добавляется **ה** *хей* , - *заглатываемая* **Х** , которая может вообще не произноситься . (От этого имени фамилия сподвижника Петра I-го генерал-адмирала Ф.М. Апраксина .) Поэтому имя новгородского священника это не есть указания на *упыря*=*ожившего мертвеца* , а просто ивритное имя <<**עפרה** Офр(ах) / Опр(ах)>> , где **ע** *аин* озвучена , как **У** , а **ה** *хей* "проглочена" . Соответствует церковно-каноническому имени <<Африкан>> . Что касается прозвища <<Лихой>> , то это , скорее всего , указание на имя <<Лех>> распространённое в Польше (Lech) . (Лех Валенса , основатель антикоммунистического движения "Солидарность" , Лех Качинский , президент Польши) .                         ========================================================================= [image: ИРИС-переводчик]

Answer (score 0):

http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Upr-4897.html
 http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Vurdalak-537.html

Вот такие две подборки по упырю и вурдалаку. Версий, как всегда, несколько, но можно понять, что упырь - скорее летучий оборотень, вурдалак - скорее волк-оборотень.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё. Взято здесь       http://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/1304680.html?nojs=1
    В  своём "Сербском словаре" 1818 года Вук
Караджич пишет, что вукóдлак это вампир,
и так называют человека, в которого на 40
день по смерти вселяется дьявольский дух,
и тот “оживает” (повампирисе). После чего
вукодлак выходит по ночам из гроба, давит
людей и пьёт их свежую кровь.
В России Караджич был хорошо известен и
уважаем, и у Пушкина этот словарь был в
его библиотеке. Был он знаком и с
“Собранием сербских песен” (1823-24 гг.)
Караджича, которые он использовал для
трёх или больше обработок в своих “Песнях
западных славян” (1835 год). И,
естественно, перекладывая и сочиняя песни
славян, Пушкин руководствовался не
французским языком (ср. “Le Morlaque à
Venice” – “Влах в Венеции”).
В примечании же Пушкин указывает там,
что “19. Вурдалаки, вудкодлаки, упыри , –
мертвецы, выходящие из своих могил и
сосущие кровь живых людей.” Включение
такого примечания говорит, что, очевидно,
эти слова были ему известны без
искажения одного в другое. Возможно, что
он и первым употребил слово вурдалак в
русской литературе, но это совсем не
значит, что оно им же и придумано.
В сербском языке есть слово “врдалама ”,
что-то типа вертушки, непоседы (как
учителя говорят школьникам), от врдати
“вертеться, быть неспокойным”, – и очень
возможно, что слово вурдалак связано с
именно таким значением “ворочающегося”
в гробу и выходящего наружу мертвеца.
Н.И. Толстой в работе “Переворачивании
предметов в славянском погребальном
обряде” пишет: “Нарушить покой
погребенного в земле покойника считалось
всегда великим грехом, и исключение
составляли те случаи и те зоны, в которых
бытовал обряд вторичного погребения.
Однако в отношении зарытых в могилу
колдунов, ведьм и вурдалаков была другая
норма поведения: если они начинали
«ходить» и беспокоить разными способами
своих близких и односельчан, с ними
поступали довольно решительно: помимо
других действий переворачивали в земле (в
гробу) со спины ничком.”
Есть бы, вроде, южнославянский же
вариант, что вурдалак это убитый или
умерший вукодлак , который по смерти стал
нежитью-вампиром, но источник на это
указать не могу.
Можно бы также заметить, что учитывая
наличие в греческом языке слов
βρυκόλακας, ή βουρβούλακες (с похожими
вуркулакас, вирколакс, вирколака) с тем же
значением «вампир» (и которые по
поверьям тоже ворочаются в гробах в
субботу или воскресенье) и наличия долгой
фольклорной традиции таких существ
(включая "Одиссею" Гомера) в Греции и
Малой Азии (Анатолии), то утверждение о
чисто славянском происхождении таких
слов может быть и не таким уж
однозначным